# Difficult probability problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am stuck in this question

$33$ miners are trapped in a mine. There´s an elevator that takes $10$ minutes to go down and another $10$ minutes to pick up a miner and return to the surface. One of the miners will have respiratory problems that will lead him to death in case he is not dealt with before $13$ minutes, and the time that he will get sick is a random variable that is uniformly distributed  $(0,20)$. If the miner gets sick before the elevator goes down then he is chosen; if he is not sick when the elevator goes down then any miner will be chosen with the same probability.
What is the probability that the miner is out in time with this method?

I am afraid I haven´t been able make any progress. I don´t know how to start it. Any suggestions/ideas will be really appreciated :)

Comment: Out in time for what?  A hot shower?

Comment: before he is death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We classify according on the time at which the sickly prisoner would have gone up before he got sick.

The complete time frame is $[0,660]$ let $20k$ denote the time in which the miner would have been selected. then the miner dies if and only if he gets sick in a point in the time frame $(20l,20l+17)$ with $l<k$ the probability of this happening is $\frac{17}{20}\frac{33}{k}=\frac{17\cdot k}{20\cdot33}$

But we need the sum from $k=0$ to $33$ and divide by $34$ so the probability is $\frac{17\cdot33\cdot34}{20\cdot33\cdot2\cdot34}=\frac{17}{40}\approx 42.5\%$

So the probability he survives is $57.5\%$

Comment: jorge fernandez I just, have a doubt why is the probability that he gets sick in a point in the time frame $(20l,20k+17)$ ${17k\over (20)(33)}$?

Comment: oops, it should have been $(20l,20l+17)$. That is the probability since if you divide the entire interval into intervals of $20$ minutes then the probability you chose a dying time within a give interval is 17/20, however only $k$ of those 33 itervals eed to be taken into account since in the others the miner is allready rescued

Comment: this is the last question I ask jorge I promise:) Why do you divide in the last part by 34?

Comment: because we calculated the probability assuming the miner was sent up at time $20k$, but the probability he was indeed sent up at time $20k$ is $\frac{1}{34}$ since $k$ can be any integer from $0$ to $33$